# Java generics: Bound mismatch: The type is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter of the type

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I am facing the following problem:

I have these class & interface definitions

```
public abstract class ViewModelRefreshPostListFragment<T extends IRefreshPostViewCallback, R extends RefreshPostViewModel<T>>
    extends RefreshPostListFragment implements IRefreshPostView {

    private final ViewModelHelper<T, R> mViewModeHelper = //error here
        new ViewModelHelper<>(); 

...
}

public abstract class RefreshPostViewModel<R1 extends IRefreshPostViewCallback> extends AbstractViewModel<IRefreshPostViewCallback> {}

public class ViewModelHelper<T extends IView, R extends AbstractViewModel<T>> {}

public abstract class AbstractViewModel<T extends IView> {}

public interface IRefreshPostViewCallback extends IView {}
```

Eclipse gives me still this error: Bound mismatch: The type `R` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<R extends AbstractViewModel<T>>` of the type `ViewModelHelper<T,R>`

Based on Java inheritance I created these 2 chains:

**"Chain" from `ViewModelRefreshPostListFragment` class definition**
1) `R extends RefreshPostViewModel<T>` -> `R extends RefreshPostViewModel<R1 extends IRefreshPostViewCallback>` -> `R extends AbstractViewModel<IRefreshPostViewCallback>`
1.1) `T extends IRefreshPostViewCallback`
1.2) `T` (from `RefreshPostViewModel<T>`) is replaced by `<R1 extends IRefreshPostViewCallback>`
Consitent result from 1.1) and 1.2) so the T parameter should be OK.

**"Chain" from ViewModelHelper class definition**
2) `R extends AbstractViewModel<T>`
2.1) `T extends IView`, `IRefreshPostViewCallback extends IView` -> `T` can be replaced by `IRefreshPostViewCallback`

If I apply 2.1) on 1.1) && 1.2) we see, parameter T is consistent

From 1) follows `R extends AbstractViewModel<IRefreshPostViewCallback>` from 2) follows  `R extends AbstractViewModel<T>`  and from 2.1) follows that `T` can be replaced by `IRefreshPostViewCallback`, 
If I understand the things correctly, this error should not appear,
could someone explain me, why is eclipse giving me the error ??

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message comes from the fact that `R` is not within its bounds.

Your `ViewModelHelper` class extends `AbstractViewModel<IRefreshPostViewCallback>`, no matter what `R1` really is.

In the class `ViewModelHelper`, change the type argument in the `extends` clause of `AbstractViewModel` to `R1`, instead of `IRefreshPostViewCallback`.

```
public abstract class RefreshPostViewModel<R1 extends IRefreshPostViewCallback>
    extends AbstractViewModel<R1>
```

and this will eliminate the error.

This will pass the proper `T` along in `ViewModelHelper`.  Instead of `R` being `RefreshPostViewModel<IRefreshPostViewCallback>`, you will be using `RefreshPostViewModel<T>`, fulfilling the bounds.

Comment: Thank you, this answer really solved my problem. I guess you accidentally wrote `ViewModelHelper` instead of `RefreshPostViewModel` 2nd and 3rd section.